# Correctly rendering a list that's called through view function

Tags: django, django-views

I previously asked this question, but it was hijacked by a troll. Here's a new one:

I have the following class in views.py. My goal is to click on a list item and see its detailview template, on which should be another list of items, all associated with this particular list item.

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

Right now, with this in the template:

```
<p>{{post}}</p>
```

it's showing (on the website):

```
<QuerySet [<Post: This is post 1>, <Post: This is post 2>, <Post: This is post 4>, <Post: This is post 5>]>
```

How can I make only the post names show? ("This is post 1" and others are the names I inputted).

Also on the template is:

```
<ul>
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class='ui card'>
    <a class="content">
      <div class="header">{{ post }}</div>
    </a>           
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <h5>You don't have any posts!</h5>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This output on the website says only "You don't have any posts!"

What's wrong, and how can I make it work? I think object_list does not belong here; what should I put here instead?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I call post twice simply to see what it does; why isn't really relevant (the foremost issue the troll had).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixing the rendering of `post`

Well first of all, you make the view *misleading*. `Post.objects.all()` is a *queryset* with *multiple* `Post`s (although it can, strictly speaking, contain zero or one `Post` as well). So I propose to use **`'posts'`** insead:

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then it works the same way as the `object_list`: you *iterate* over it:

```
<ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class='ui card'>
    <a class="content">
      <div class="header">{{ post }}</div>
    </a>           
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <h5>You don't have any posts!</h5>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

That being said, it looks like you actually want a **`ListView`** with as `model` the `Post`s, so change `DetailView` to `ListView`, perhaps change the `template_name`, change `model = Book` to `model = Post`, and drop the `get_context_data(..)` function. You can then *iterate* over the `object_list` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I make the suggested changes, I get: Reverse for 'books' not found. 'books' is not a valid view function or pattern name. What might be the problem?

Comment: @thebot: looks to me that you have in your template a `{% url %}` that makes no sense.

Comment: On the last point, I want to click on a list of books to see a list of posts regarding that particular book. Would using ListView on this ListView of books work? If so, I will try and post question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @thebot: well I would then make a `ListView` to see the *list* of books, and a `DetailView` to see a *specific* book.

Comment: So when I click on a DetailView to see a specific book, instead of book description I want to see a list of posts about this book. Would you still recommend using ListView for this list of posts? This sounds like something I'd have to learn more about.

Comment: I haven't worked out the model association yet (foreignkey) and have never built something like this before (newbie). If using a separate ListView for Post would be better for this purpose, please let me know!

Comment: @thebot: well of course that depends a bit, but a `ListView` is typically used to display a list, and a detail view, is typically used to show the *details* of a single element.